# Ether gas fees, environmental impact?

Tags: gas, fees

It is my understanding that gas fees paid in Ether are more like tips given to validators to prioritize their tasks when there is a high volume of traffic.

For example, Investopedia states [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gas-ethereum.asp):

> "The concept of gas was introduced to compensate miners for their work
> done on maintaining and securing the blockchain. Ater the proof of
> stake algorithm was rolled out in September 2022, gas fees became the
> reward for staking ETH and participating in validation—the more a user
> has staked, the more they can earn."

After the transition to PoS, it sounds like gas fee is like a service tip to have the validation faster. My question is:

Does gas fee have environmental impacts?

On the web, it talks about gas fees are for computing power of miners or validators. Then, doesn't this actually impact computing costs therefore have environmental implications?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145880/discussion-on-question-by-frank-swanton-ether-gas-fees-environmental-impact); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Hard to understand this question. What do you mean by environmental impact and what are examples of Yes and No for it? Does using a bank have environmental impact? Or paying a bank fee?